# Accessing the Calender in iPhone

Tags: iphone, calendar

can i access the iphone calendar using SDK ??
is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible since iOS 4.0 SDK with **EventKit**.

You can access the calendar through `EKEventStore` class.

Comment: SimpleEKDemo: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleEKDemo/Introduction/Intro.html (look at fetchEventsForToday)

Answer (score 0):

Apple has introduced `Event Kit Framework` in iOS4 by using which  you can display or create a calendar entry.

For Reference you can refer to [Event Kit Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004759-SW1)

Also you can refer to this tutorial for [Event Kit Framework integration.](http://mobileorchard.com/ios-advanced-programming-event-kit-framework/)